# How Do I Retrieve a List of Users Who Has includeInGlobalAddressList set to false?

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am looking for a way to retrieve all of the users in my domain that have a value of includeInGlobalAddressList=false . Is there a way to do this via the API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do so via the API.  The full list of searchable query attribute is [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users), and it doesn't look like includeInGlobalAddressList is one of it.

Comment: I will hold off marking your response as an answer in case there's some voodoo that can be done.

It kind of stinks that you can query the Directory API for all the users where includeInGlobalAddressList=true, but there's no way to get a list of users where includeInGlobalAddressList=false.